# Find the most popular first name for women in 1885, 1915, 1945, 1975, and 2005 using SparkSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I need to find the most popular first name for women in 1885, 1915, 1945, 1975, and 2005.

TABLE INFO:

SSANames (firstName, year, gender)

EXAMPLE OF EXPECTED OUTPUT:

firstName / year / total_count
(Martha, 1885, 732)
(Bessy, 1915, 1004)
(Charlotte, 1945, 999)
(Ashley, 1975, 574)
(Jessica, 2005, 942)

Having trouble figuring out how to create this query.

Here is where I am...

```
SELECT
  firstName,
  year,
  count(firstName) AS total_count
FROM SSANames
WHERE
  year IN ("1885", "1915", "1945", "1975", "2005")
GROUP BY
  firstName,
  year
```

I then need to run MAX on the total_count column for the given years, and return the associated firstName, but I'm unsure of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT yf.*
FROM (SELECT year, firstName, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM SSANames
      WHERE year IN (1885, 1915, 1945, 1975, 2005) AND
            gender = 'F'
      GROUP BY year, firstName
     ) yf
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note that in the event of ties, this returns an arbitrary most common value.  If you want all of them, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi! I think this is the answer you are looking for:**

```
SELECT firstName, year, total
FROM (
      SELECT firstName, gender, year, total, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR ORDER BY TOTAL DESC) AS ROW_NUM
      FROM SSANames 
      WHERE gender = 'F' AND year IN (1885, 1915, 1945, 1975,2005) 
      GROUP BY firstName, gender, year, total ORDER BY total DESC
      ) SS
WHERE SS.ROW_NUM = 1
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't see how your answer differs from the other answer. In fact, if I compare the two answers, it appears that yours contains an error. What is column `total`?

Comment: @Abra  He's looking for a total, for example (Martha, 1885, 732), where 732 is the total.
A few weeks ago I came across this exercise to develop, and the question was:

**Use the SSANames table to find the most popular first name for girls in 1885, 1915, 1945, 1975, and 2005. The table SSANames Has 4 columms (firstName,gender, year,total)**

Comment: @Abra and the output has to be: **firstName, year, total**

Answer (score 0):

You can answer this question by using Spark SQL's Window Functions like this.

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW HistoricNames AS
SELECT
  firstName, year, total
FROM (
  SELECT
    firstName, year, total,
    dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY total DESC) as rank
  FROM SSANames
  WHERE year IN (1885, 1915, 1945, 1975, 2005) AND gender = 'F'
  ) tmp
WHERE
  rank = 1
ORDER BY total
```

Read more about it [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution without using any window function but it does scan the `SSANames` table twice. Would be interested in knowing how to optimize this without using any window functions.

```
create table HistoricNames as
select lt.* from 
(
  select firstName, year, total 
  from SSANames
  where gender = 'F'
  and year in (1885, 1915, 1945, 1975, 2005)
) lt, 
( 
select year, max(total) as total from SSANames where gender = 'F' and year in (1885, 1915, 1945, 1975, 2005) group by year
) rt
where lt.year = rt.year and lt.total = rt.total;
```